# Webhook.send(<message>) discord.py doesn't return anything

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, discord.py

Like said in the title, if I were to do something like :

```py
webhook = await channel.create_webhook(name='test')
msg = await webhook.send(content='test', username='Useless Webhook')
print(f"{msg}\n{type(msg)}")
```

It returns :

```
None
<class 'NoneType'>
```

And in the discord documentation :

> ````
> Returns
> The message that was sent.
> Return type
> Optional[Message]```
> ````

Don't know how to solve that problem...

My goal here is to delete the message that was sent by the webhook after some time (like 2sec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it wasn't very difficult, I had just to add the `wait` parameter set to `True` in `webhook.send()`

(I thought the `wait` parameter may delay the message)